# How to create page and restrict it to authenticated users?

Tags: 7, users

I'm using the [empty_page](http://drupal.org/project/empty_page) module to create "myhome" page and show blocks with a user's own content. That page throws an error for authenticated users.

How can I create an empty page in code and throw a 403 error when a visitors tries to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override using the hook_theme, even though this module doesn't actually give you any real themeable output.

Copy the function empty_page_menu() from line 26 onwards in file empty_page.module to your themes template.php. Rename it to YOUR_THEME_NAME_menu()
The last bit says:

```
// Create the dynamic callbacks.
 foreach (empty_page_get_callbacks() as $cid => $callback) {
  $items[$callback->path] = array(
   'title' => t($callback->page_title),
   'page callback' => 'empty_page_empty',
   'access callback' => TRUE,
   'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
  );
 }

 return $items;
}
```

Change this line

```
'page callback' => 'empty_page_empty',
```

to maybe

```
'page callback' => 'empty_page_empty_secure',
```

Now copy the empty_page_empty() function in empty_page.module

```
/**
 * An Empty Page callback's empty content.
 *
 * @return string $output
 */
 function empty_page_empty() {
  return '';
 }
```

Rename it to empty_page_empty_secure() and add a simple check:
 something like

```
 function empty_page_empty_secure() {
   if(user_is_logged_in()) {
     return '';
   } else {
     // go to your 403 page
   }
 }
```

Note that I havn't tried this, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [Frontpage](http://drupal.org/project/frontpage) module - it allows you to set different home pages for authenticated and unauthenticated users.

Comment: I've looked at Frontpage but it didn't work in my case for 2 reasons: The real home page should still be "/". The user's "myhome" page is "/myhome". That page shows 5 views blocks that all have a contextual filter using the "userid from logged in user". The "myhome" page is created with the "empty_page" module.

Comment: Did you try setting the blocks on the home page to only display for authenticated users? Conversely, you can set different blocks to only show up for anonymous users.

Comment: thanks. Restricting the access to the blocks prevents error from showing.

Comment: No prob - how about that bounty?

Comment: sorry, the other answer was the perfect solution to my problem ;-)